# Force audio routing to speaker (and optionally route to BT if user preferences) and setStreamType ignored by Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

My goal is the following, I want to give the user the following options in preferences:

- Play sounds: "Always on speaker" or "Use Bluetooth when available"
- Use stream: `STREAM_MUSIC`, `STREAM_ALARM`, `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` or `STREAM_RING`

My first problem is that when a user has a (Lollipop) device connected to an a2dp enabled device (car stereo), I can't seem to get the sound to get played through the device speaker. (The sound also isn't being played through the a2dp device)

The second problem I encounter is that `setStreamType` somehow stopped working since Lollipop? On Lollipop `setStreamType` is ignored and sound is always played through `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`? (On device pre-Lollipop the same code still works)

```
private void playSound() {
    try {

        if (am == null) am = (AudioManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);



        if (am.isWiredHeadsetOn() || am.isBluetoothA2dpOn()){
            am.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
            am.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
//          am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); // bel speaker
//          am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false); // bel speaker
            am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); // media speaker
            am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true); // media speaker
        } else {
//          am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); // bel speaker
//          am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false); // bel speaker
            am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL); // media speaker
            am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true); // media speaker
        }


        Class audioSystemClass = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
        Method setForceUse = audioSystemClass.getMethod("setForceUse",
            int.class,
            int.class);
        // 1 == FOR_MEDIA, 10 == FORCE_NO_BT_A2DP (FORCE_SPEAKER would be 1).
        setForceUse.invoke(null, 1, 1);

        alarmsound = _prefs.getString("alarm", alarmsound);

        as = Uri.parse(alarmsound);

        if (mp == null) mp = MediaPlayer.create(_context, as);
        mp.reset();
        if (alarmsound.startsWith("content://settings/system/"))
            mp.setDataSource(_context, Uri.parse("android.resource://nl.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx/raw/beep"));
        else setMediaPlayerDataSource(_context, mp, as.toString());

        mp.setAudioStreamType(Globals.AudioStreamType);

        mp.prepare();

        long alarmDuration = mp.getDuration();
        mp.start();

}
```

From the Globals class:
`public static int AudioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;` (this can be changed by the user to the other stream types)

I declared uses-permission `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` in the Manifest.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You ever find anything? Having the same problem now.